# Calculating and extracting occurrence of unique element/gene within row in all column in a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, filter

I have very large sizes csv files and searching for unique gene in presence absence data, as well as their count. my data is as follows

```
df <- data.frame(
      A = c("G1", "G2", "G3", "G4", "G5","G6","G7", "G8", "G9","G10"),
      B = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0),
      C = c(1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0),
      D = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1),
      E = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
```

output is as follows 1st one is data frame with unique gene

```
df_uniq <- data.frame(
  A = c("G4", "G5","G6","G7", "G8", "G9","G10"),
  B = c(0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0),
  C = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0),
  D = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1),
  E = c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0))
```

Appreciate for your help Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `dplyr` solution

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df_uniq <- df %>%
   filter(reduce(pick(-A), `+`) == 1)
> df_uniq
    A B C D E
1  G4 0 0 0 1
2  G5 1 0 0 0
3  G6 1 0 0 0
4  G7 1 0 0 0
5  G8 0 1 0 0
6  G9 0 1 0 0
7 G10 0 0 1 0
df_uniq %>%
   reframe(across(-1, sum))
  B C D E
1 3 2 1 1
```

Or in `base R`

```
df_uniq <- subset(df, Reduce(`+`, df[-1]) == 1)
colSums(df_uniq[-1])
B C D E 
3 2 1 1
```

Comment: I want to extract unique first than adding,

Answer (score 1):

A `dplyr` solution:

```r
library(dplyr)

df_uniq <- df %>%
  filter(rowSums(pick(-A)) == 1)

#      A B C D E
# 4   G4 0 0 0 1
# 5   G5 1 0 0 0
# 6   G6 1 0 0 0
# 7   G7 1 0 0 0
# 8   G8 0 1 0 0
# 9   G9 0 1 0 0
# 10 G10 0 0 1 0

df_uniq %>%
  summarise(across(-A, sum))

#   B C D E
# 1 3 2 1 1
```

---

Equivalent in `base`:

```r
df_uniq <- df[rowSums(df[-1]) == 1, ]
sapply(df_uniq[-1], sum)
```

Comment: why did u use -1, I didnt get how it will work

Comment: @mdumar `df[-1]` means to exclude the first column from `df`. You can run `df` and `df[-1]` to see the difference. `rowSums()` sums the data by rows. The first column is character that cannot be summed, so it has to be excluded.